# RestTemplateBuilder: problem sending audio to telegram api

Tags: java, telegram-bot, resttemplate, sendfile

I use RestTemaplteBuilder for send POST request to Telegram Bot API.
There was a problem creating the request to upload the audio file.
According to the documentation - https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files you need to send a request of type multipart/form-data. 
Error: 413 Request Entity Too Large

```
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> request= new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    try {
        parts.set("chat_id", "id");
        parts.set("audio", (Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("name.mp3").toURI()))));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(request, headers);

    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplateBuilder.build().postForEntity(requestFormatter(URL_BOT_PREFIX, method), requestEntity, String.class);
```